# Why can I not use int parameter in Cython in Jupyterlab?

Tags: cython

I am trying to use Cython in Jupyterlab:

```py
%load_ext Cython
%%cython -a
    
def add (int x, int y):
    cdef int result
    result = x + y
    return result
add(3,67)
```

error:

```
File "<ipython-input-1-e496e2665826>", line 9
    def add (int x, int y):
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What am I missing?

Comment: %load_ext Cython should be in its own cell. The next cell should start with %%cython. Otherwise everything is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update:

I just measured `cpdef` vs `def` and the difference between score was quite a low one (45(`cpdef`) vs 52(`def`), smaller = better/faster), so for your function it might not matter if called just a few times, but having that chew through a large amount of data might do some real difference.

If that's not applicable for you, just call that `%load_ext` in a separate cell, keep `def` and that should be enough.

(Cython 0.29.24, GCC 9.3.0, x86_64)

---

Use [`cpdef`](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/pyrex_differences.html#cpdef-functions) to make it C-like function, but also to expose it to Python, so you can call it from Jupyter (because Jupyter is using Python, unless specified by the `%%cython` magic func). Also, check the [Early Binding for Speed](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/early_binding_for_speed.html#early-binding-for-speed) section.

```py
cpdef add (int x, int y):
    cdef int result
    result = x + y
    return result
```

Also make sure to check [Using the Jupyter notebook](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/quickstart/build.html#using-the-jupyter-notebook) which explains that the `%` needs to be in a separate cell as [ead](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5769463/ead) mentioned in the comments.

Comment: It's probably better left as a `def` function. Those are compiled too. Unless you're calling it very frequently from Cython there's really no benefit in making it `cpdef`

Comment: @DavidW thanks for that, I've updated the answer with the measurements

Comment: Separating the `%load_ext Cython` did nothing. Using `cpef` pointed at the second `d` in `add` but same error.

Comment: I had a comment prior to `%%cython`. Removed that and put `%load_ext Cython` in its own cell and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

`add` has to be defined with `cdef`, not `def`.

```
cdef add (int x, int y):
    cdef int result
    result = x + y
    return result
add(3,67)
```

Comment: In cython is totally ok to type arguments in a def function ( even more cdef functions aren’t accessible from pure python).